# Tor not working after update

Tags: 14.04, tor, apparmor

Yesterday I updated my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and after that Tor stopped working :

When I try to run Tor using command

`sudo service tor start` it gives an error

```
aa-exec: ERROR: profile 'system_tor' does not exist
```

prior to the update everything was working fine.

Comment: Did you use Tor from Ubuntu or from the Tor project?

Comment: @qbi from ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but I just checked and `/etc/apparmor.d/system_tor` is present in my system.

What it looks to be the cause of the problem is the init script `/etc/init.d/tor` that is calling `aa-exec` in a wrong way ( at least it is not working ):

**Solution:**

- Edit `/etc/init.d/tor`
- At line 159 you should have this:
  `AA_EXEC_ARGS="--profile=system_tor -- $DAEMON"`
  **Change it with**
  `AA_EXEC_ARGS="-f system_tor -- $DAEMON"`

Now the service load fine for me but I have to say I don't know the difference between `-f` and `--profile` option.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if the file `/etc/apparmor.d/system_tor` exists. 
I suppose it does not, because it was removed somehow and therefore the warning that it does not exist anymore.

`/etc/apparmor.d/system_tor` is provided by package `tor` in ubuntu.
(see http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/tor/filelist)

So simply reinstall tor from the official software sources and everything should be fine.

Comment: I have the same error but `/etc/apparmor.d/system_tor` is present in my system